# Shake: How to set an environment variable upon invocation?

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments, shake-build-system

In a Makefile, one can refer to arguments set at the command line at the time one invokes `make`. For instance, the recipe in a rule might include the command `python/subsample.py $(subsample_size)`, which one invokes at the command line by typing something like `make subsample subsample_size=0.1`.

I would like to do the same thing with `shake`. I've written the following rule:

```
phony "echoEnvVar" $ do
    ev <- fromMaybe "undefined" <$> getEnv "ev"
    liftIO $ putStrLn ev
```

The problem is that `shake` is treating the command-line definition of the `ev` variable as another target:

```
jeff@jeff-ThinkCentre-M700:~/shake-studies$ stack exec  ./build.sh echoEnvVar ev=whatever
Error when running Shake build system:
* ev=whatever
Error, file does not exist and no rule available:
  ev=whatever
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at src/Development/Shake/Internal/Rules/File.hs:180:58 in shake-0.16.4-7UipAYwzJlKKX7fQ0hMQ1b:Development.Shake.Internal.Rules.File
```

If I instead call that rule with no command-line arguments, it behaves as expected:

```
jeff@jeff-ThinkCentre-M700:~/shake-studies$ stack exec  ./build.sh echoEnvVar
undefined
Build completed in 0:01m
jeff@jeff-ThinkCentre-M700:~/shake-studies$
```

Answer (score 3):

When you say

```sh
make subsample subsample_size=0.1
```

You invoke `make` with two arguments: `subsample` and `subsample_size=0.1`, and with the same environment the rest of your shell is in. `make` recognizes that `subsample_size=0.1` has the form `var=value`, and it interprets this as a macro definition. Doing so happens to have the same effect as setting an environment variable. Shake does not support taking definitions on the command line, so you must *actually* set an environment variable.

The way you set the environment variable for Shake will depend on what program you are using to execute Shake. You are invoking Shake through a `build.sh`. Assuming this doesn't do anything too interesting, the script will pass its own environment to Shake unchanged. You are invoking `build.sh` through `stack exec`, which will pass your variable from its own environment unchanged as well (but it does change certain other variables). You are invoking `stack exec` through your own shell. Assuming that it is a POSIX shell, you can write

```sh
ev="Hello World!" stack exec ./build.sh echoEnvVar
```

to set the `ev` environment variable during the call to `stack`. You can also use the [`export` builtin](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/export.html).

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is an environment variable then @HTNW's answer is spot on.

If what you really want is configuration options that are available in the program then you can use [`shakeArgsWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake/docs/Development-Shake.html#v:shakeArgsWith). As an example:

```
import System.Console.GetOpt

flags = [Option "" ["subsample_size"] (ReqArg readEither) "Set the subsample size (in %)."]

main = shakeArgsWith shakeOptions flags $ \flags targets -> return $ Just $ do
    -- now flags will contain a list of the passed subsample_size values
    ...
```